# Kaza to Manali via Rohtang Pass in bus / shared vehicle

Tags: public-transport, india, himalayas, ride-sharing

I am planning to travel through this route entirely in bus/shared vehicles:
    Delhi → Shimla → Rampur → Peo → Pooh → Kaza → Rohtang Pass → Manali → Kulu → Delhi

Earlier I covered Delhi to Pooh and Manali to Delhi easily using HRTC buses. **Hence my question is only regarding Kaza to Manali via Rohtang**

What about the connection between Kaza and Manali? Are there any bus services or cheap sharing vehicle services? I like to travel, but I can't afford private transport.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about constructing itineraries.

Comment: @AdityaSomani: did I miss that part? The itinerary seems pretty established to me. The OP is looking specifically for a public/shared transport connection between Kaza and Manali.

Comment: @NickStauner You're absolutely right! I missed that part earlier. After the better formatting, it's much easier to understand. My apologies to the OP for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit obscure, [this was the only information](http://www.solobackpacker.com/2012/06/18/road-journeys-from-delhi-to-spiti-valley/) I was able to find on your issue,

> **Manali-Kaza:** When this 210 km route is open, there are **two daily ordinary buses leaving from Manali Bus Stand to Kaza at 5.00 AM and 5.30 AM**. These buses are run by Himachal Roadways and fare is approximately INR 200. The bus passes through Rohtang Pass, Batal, Kunzum Pass, Lossur and takes about 11 hours to reach Kaza.
>
> **Important point is that once the route is declared open by the authorities, you do not get the public buses for next 2-3 weeks.** They only allow small vehicles to run on the road initially. **In this period, you can get a shared sumo/jeep.** A shared sumo between Manali and Kaza cost you Rs.700 and takes 9 hours to complete this trip.

I'm not going to say that you should take mine or this man's word for it, but it would be similar to taking someone else's word on it. Most others will be able to tell you something similar by experience as it seems that published information regarding routes in this area is rare if any.